# Replicate specific rows and separate str column values pandas

Tags: pandas, replicate

I have the following dataframe

```
index city              pop
1     London           1000
2     Buenos Aires     2054
3     New York         34544
4     Paris-Madrid     34343
5     Barcelona-Lagos  64544
```

What I expect to do:

```
index city              pop
1     London           1000
2     Buenos Aires     2054
3     New York         34544
4     Paris            34343
5     Madrid           34343
6     Barcelona        64544  
7     Lagos            64544
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`split` + `explode`

```
df=df.assign(city=df.city.str.split('-')).explode('city').reset_index(drop=True)
   index         city    pop
0      1       London   1000
1      2  BuenosAires   2054
2      3      NewYork  34544
3      4        Paris  34343
4      4       Madrid  34343
5      5    Barcelona  64544
6      5        Lagos  64544
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you! Edit: What is "drop=True" on reset_index for?

Comment: @Guerra if not add , it will add the index as column in you dataframe